# UV Texture doesn't show on my model

Tags: texturing

I seem i have put My Texture in the UV Map,but it doesn't show up In the Model itself
https://gyazo.com/0f3bd1087814d915fb5dd3d3a37d1df0
I don't really Know blender that well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to switch your "viewport shading" mode to either material or texture. Then you probably will be able to see it.
http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/_images/Viewport-shading-menu.jpg